# How to prevent the keyboard enter event after entering 10 characters in react quill editor?

Tags: react-quill

```
function onkeydown(e) {
if (e.key === "enter")
e.preventDefault()
}
<ReactQuill onKeyDown={onkeydown}/>
```

Here iam unable to prevent the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this.

```
function onkeydown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

Since the keyCode of the `Enter` key event is `13`
}

Comment: Even if i compare it with keyCode same result.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? update your question will reproducible code sample.

Comment: I have a react quill editor which need to have only 3 rows, untill we come to row 3 enter key should work after that i need to prevent the enter key.

Comment: update your question with your component code.